# What's causing the file is not executable by user on the windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: bash, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish

This seems to have randomly started a few days ago. It used to be fine to run fish shell from Ubuntu bash for Windows. But suddenly when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> for autocomplete, it barfs with:

```
The file "x86" is not executable by this user in command substitution called on standard input
```

Also, when I just type `x86` it doesn't actually run a command, but it tells me:

```
The file "x86" is not executable by this user
```

However, `which x86` outputs nothing.

Any clue what in the world could be going on here?

Comment: whats your pwd? are you on or evaluating a path to c:\program files (x86)\ ? bash is likely to parse that as multiple file names. windows should never have allowed whitespace in filenames...

Comment: Ah, it looks like ` /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common` (among a few others) is on my PATH. Is there a way to either eliminate those, as they're not even remotely relevant for the subsystem.... I mean, I could manually set the PATH of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug present in fish [and fixed in version 2.3.0](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/2912) - if it is still present in later versions, a report would be greatly appreciated.

You can install a newer version from [the Ubuntu PPA repositories](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2) if the version installed by `apt-get` is too old.

Comment: You r question solves the problem, mine just rambles :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is in `completer_t::complete_cmd`, which invokes expand_string. This is a very general function that expands things like wildcards, process expansion, variable expansion, etc.

It's surely wrong to do these expansions in the components of $PATH.